# Stuck on Ajax Form to mysql submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am good in php and html, however my I am still learning js. And I am stuck on creating a form which will submit form data to be inserted in mysql without loading page(ajax).

Below is my form:

```
<form id="panel1" action="rep-submit.php" method="post">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="rep_author" id="rep_author" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control">
                                 </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" name="rep_email" id="rep_email" placeholder="Your Email" class="form-control">
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                      <textarea class="form-control" id="rep_comment" name ="rep_comment"rows="3" placeholder="Your comment"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $comment_id; ?>" id ="rep_to">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $postp_id; ?>" id ="rep_post_id">
                               <input id="repsub" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                               </form>
```

Below is my post.js I took a lot of online guide to make such js codes :P, it took 1 day to complete still not working. Please help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#repsub").on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
                            $("#repsub").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            var rep_author = $('#rep_author').val();        
                            var rep_email = $('#rep_email').val();      
                            var rep_comment = $('#rep_comment').val();
                            var rep_to = $('#rep_to').val();
                            var rep_post_id = $('#rep_post_id').val();
                            var url = $("#panel1").attr("action");
                            alert(url);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: url, 
                                type: "POST",
                                data: {
                                rep_author: rep_author, 
                                rep_email: rep_email,
                                rep_comment: rep_comment,
                                rep_to: rep_to,
                                rep_post_id: rep_post_id
            },
            cache: false,   
            success: function(dataResult){
                var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);    
                document.write(rep_comment);    

                if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                        console.log("success");
                        $("#repsub").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $('#panel1').find('input:text').val('');
                        alert("success");
                        }
                        else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){                     
                        alert("Error occured !");                   
                        }
                        }

                            });
                            });
                            });
```

Finally below is rep-submit.php

```
    <?php include_once("includes/connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['rep_submit']))
    {
        global $connection;
        connection();
        $author = $_POST['rep_author'];
        $email = $_POST['rep_email'];
        $comment = $_POST['rep_comment'];
        $rep_to = $_POST['rep_to'];
        $post_id = $_POST['rep_post_id'];
       $com_rep = "yes,".$rep_to;

        $query = "INSERT INTO comment(comment_post_id,comment_author,comment_email,comment_content,comment_reply) ";
        $query .= "VALUES('$post_id','$author','$email','$comment','$com_rep')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if(!$result)
            {
                echo "There is some issue posting your reply on that comment<br>";
                echo mysqli_error($connection);
                echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>201)); 
        }   
            else
            {
                echo "reply sucessfully sent for approval";

        $query = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE comment_id = '$rep_to'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $com_count = $row['comment_reply_count'];
        $new_count = $com_count + 1;
        $query = "UPDATE comment SET ";
        $query .= "comment_reply_count = '$new_count' ";
        $query .= "WHERE comment_id = '$rep_to'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>200));
        }   


    }
?>
```

Comment: Which specific part is causing problems? What's going wrong?

Comment: i suspect the javascript function isn't called please try <input id="#repsub"

Comment: Thank you so much for assist replies, so form is displaying, when i click submit button it's css attribute changes to disable as defined in js but doesnt execute what is written in rep-submit.php, I believe that success: part is not working in ajax js. For sql injection this is just learning files(localhost) and will soon add escape real strings. I added **#**repsub but it is not working :(

Comment: I'm curious whether the AJAX is firing and the PHP file is being called. Does the `alert()` fire? Does `success` fire? Do you see the PHP file being requested in your browser console? Are there any associated errors?

Comment: When i click submit i see that form fields are submitted but there is no response. That alert(url) works great. On success part i added Document.write to test whether it works or not but it didnt worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working as intended because you need to call the `preventDefault()` method of the `click` event your Javascript code is listening to.

You have to change this part of your code:

```
$("#repsub").on('click', function() {
```

to this:

```
$("#repsub").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

In this way, you prevent the default behavior of your submit button `#repsub`, which is to submit the `#panel1` form.

Also, you have to add `rep_submit: 1` to the data object you send via AJAX:

```
data: {
    rep_author: rep_author, 
    rep_email: rep_email,
    rep_comment: rep_comment,
    rep_to: rep_to,
    rep_post_id: rep_post_id,
    rep_submit: 1 // Add this
},
```

Most of your PHP code wasn't executed because the `rep_submit` element in the AJAX request was missing: `isset($_POST['rep_submit'])` returned `false`.

In addition, there is an important error in your HTML code: your `#repsub` input is of type `submit.`. You need to remove the dot by changing it to `submit` in order to correctly show a form submit button.

The last problem is that in the PHP, in case of success, you are echoing some text before echoing the final json-encoded data. You have to remove the line `echo "reply sucessfully sent for approval";`. This way, your JS code will be able to parse the response and show the "success" alert.

---

### Other considerations

I think it would be better if you handle the `submit` event of your form instead of the `click` event of your submit input. To do this, you should simply change your code this way:

```
$("#panel1").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

---

You should't use `document.write()`, especially if the code which calls it is asynchronous (it will overwrite all the page content). Use [Node.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or JQuery's [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) and [prepend()](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) methods.

---

You should be outputting data from your PHP in a consistent way. If you want to use JSON, then always return correct JSON data and don't use `echo` for other purposes. In this case, to keep it simple, you could output this data on success:

```
{
    "success": true
}
```

In case of error, output this:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error_message": "Your error message"
}
```

In this way, you will be able to handle your server responses in a simple and clean way.

---

Dharman's comment is correct: you need to prevent SQL injection. You can find some good information on how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

---

**Useful links**

- event.preventDefault() - [Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have updated my code in ky question as you said but it is still same as it was before, I have taken a screen recording you can see it here https://gamerli.tk/2019/07/19/video-ajax-form-submission/ sorry i am currently in mobile

Comment: I see, thanks for the video! I found other problems I didn't notice before and updated my answer, everything should be OK now

Comment: Ok now it is inserting data in database :) but that if(dataResult.statusCode==200) doesnt get executed, i tried else (which js has to do if any condition fails) but it didnt do anything. When I click submit button becomes disabled and data gets inserted into database and there is no alert box coming

Comment: It's a problem with the data you're outputting in the PHP. Check my updated answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, it will help me learning js, I want to give you upvote but whenever i click up arrow it rolls back -_- , i think its because reputation :P

Comment: I'm happy that we managed to solve the problem :) You don't need to upvote the answer, just [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so others will know that the problem is solved